# ExtJS 4.1 event delegation not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4.1 and trying to do the event delegation which in my case is to attach a blur event to all the textfields of my form and it is not working and i am not getting any error in firebug too, i don't know where i am going wrong in attaching the event, is it the wrong place where i am putting the code and also i have noticed that as per the docs below link:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-on

the delegate property of the options object no longer exists. Below is my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var loadForm = function () {
        Ext.getCmp('TestForm').getForm().setValues({ name: 'some text', email: 'first', dob: '12/12/2009' });
    }


    Ext.define('userForm', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel'
            , alias: 'widget.userform'
            , frame: true
          , initComponent: function () {


              Ext.apply(this, {
                  title: 'User Form'
                , height: 350
                , items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                   , fieldLabel: 'Name'
                   , name: 'name'
                   , id: 'nameId'
                   , enableKeyEvents: true
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                   , fieldLabel: 'Email'
                   , name: 'email'
                   , id: 'emailId'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'DOB',
                    id: 'dob',
                    name: 'dob',
                    format: 'Y-m-d'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Age',
                    id: 'age',
                    name: 'age'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Guardian',
                    id: 'guardian',
                    name: 'guardian'
                }]


              });


              this.callParent(arguments);
          } //eoinitComponent


    });


    var userForm = Ext.create('userForm', {
        renderTo: 'loadPanel',
        id: 'TestForm',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (formCmp, eOpts) {
                loadForm();
            },
            render: function (formCmp, eOpts) {
                Ext.getCmp("TestForm").on(
                            'blur',
                            function (e, t) {
                                // handle blur
                                console.info(t.id);
                            },
                            this,
                            {
                                // filter the target element to be a descendant with the class '.x-form-field'
                                delegate: '.x-form-field'
                            }
                        );
            }
        }


    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, the `on` method does not take `delegate` as a parameter, so that line is completely unnecessary.

Then, within your render event, you can just use `formCmp.on()` rather than `Ext.getCmp().on()`.

Lastly, you want blur event on every field, not on the form itself. The following code should work:

```
render: function (formCmp, eOpts) {
    // For each field.
    formCmp.getForm().getFields().each( function( aField )  {
        // If it's a textfield.
        if ( aField.is('textfield') ) {
            aField.on( 'blur', this.onFieldBlur, this)
        }
    }, this ); // notice the this scope for the each method.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the right answer is, but I don't think this one qualifies as using "event delegation" since it is attaching a listener to each field.  Unless I'm mistaken, event delegation involves attaching a listener to just one element, and then handling multiple events from its descendents.

Comment: Event delegation happens on the object (instance) level not the class (definition), so it has nothing to do with descendants. Delegation means that instead of instance X dealing with the notification, instance Y will.

Comment: I was speaking of descendents as in the DOM, not object-oriented inheritance.

Comment: Well, the notifications in question happen on the ExtJS instance level, not on the DOM level.

Comment: I get that, but this still isn't event delegation since it's registering a listener on each field component.  Event delegation would be attaching ONE listener to a parent (i.e., container) component that could handle events originating from any/all of the fields that it contains.  I'm not saying this won't work--it's just not event delegation, IMHO.